# Lightning landing page - discern if landed from login versus click

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to redirect user to a different tab if there's certain condition happens upon logging into the app.

When user lands to page, is it possible to know whether he just logged in versus just clicked on the tab?

Comment: You might want to check `retURl` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dzh -- You should be able to do what you need by using a "custom login flow"

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_login_flow.htm&type=5